# SQL query for date range as columns

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have data stored in this format:

```
Name | Order Date | Order Amount
---
```

I need it displayed such as:

```
Name | Jun 16-30 | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | ... | May | Jun 1 - 15
---
```

With order amount summed under each date range/month.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a pivot, or sum with a case?  I need to sum where day/month is between dates, but year is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general format for using conditional aggregation in MS Access is:

```
select name,
       sum(iif(datepart("month", OrderDate) 6 and datepart("day", OrderDate) between 16 and 30, OrderAmount, 0)) as [Jun 16-30],
       sum(iif(datepart("month", OrderDate) = 7, OrderAmount, 0) as [Jul],
       . . .
from t
group by name;
```